# Pytorch GPU implementation is much slower than Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

can someone explain to me why this simple operation takes so much time using pytorch with GPU? I understand that maybe the equation is not so hard for CPU (numpy code) but still, 0.6899s seems to be horrible when I used pytorch for much harder problems with more samples and it took 4ms. Is there a way to make that function much more efficient? Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import time

# Define the functions to be tested
ndof = 2
x_dim = 20
n_samples = 1000

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
def NP_cost(x):
    x_t_minus1 = np.concatenate((x[:, :ndof], x[:, :(x_dim - ndof)]), axis=1)
    x_t_minus2 = np.concatenate((x_t_minus1[:, :ndof], x_t_minus1[:, :(x_dim - ndof)]), axis=1)
    k_order = x + x_t_minus2 - 2 * x_t_minus1
    return np.sum(k_order ** 2, axis=1)

def GPU_cost(x):
    x_tensor = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
    x_t_minus1 = torch.cat([x_tensor[:,:ndof], x_tensor[:, :(x_dim - ndof)]], dim=1)
    x_t_minus2 = torch.cat([x_t_minus1[:,:ndof], x_t_minus1[:,:(x_dim - ndof)]], dim=1)
    k_order = x_tensor + x_t_minus2 - 2*x_t_minus1
    return torch.sum(k_order**2, dim=1).cpu().numpy()


# Generate a random input array
x = np.random.rand(n_samples, x_dim)

# Test the functions and measure execution time
start_time = time.time()
print(NP_cost(x)[0])    
print(f"NP_cost execution time: {time.time() - start_time:.4f} seconds")    # 0.0003 seconds

start_time = time.time()
print(GPU_cost(x)[0])
print(f"GPU_cost execution time: {time.time() - start_time:.4f} seconds")   # 0.6899 seconds
```

Comment: You should move the 'print()' calls out of code region you are trying to time.

Comment: Measure computation time only, not copying data from cpu-to-gpu and gpu-to-cpu

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert at this, but I tried this code, and it's probably just a bunch of copying back and forth and not much compute for a gpu.
Tried it with n_samples = 10000000, where the gpu did it faster.

4.644260007225965
NP_cost execution time: 3.8376 seconds
4.6442604
GPU_cost execution time: 2.0928 seconds

Gpu execution needs your tensors to be copied to the device, make the computation, and copy it back. Concatenation is really just another few copies.
The only real compute you have is a few additions, a subtraction, square, and a sum, which is not much compared to how many data elements you have. I would like to hear someone else's opinion though with more experience.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @balazon I have found out that creating the tensor takes over 600ms, which is most of the time. After putting the `torch.cuda.synchronize()` command at the beginning of the code, creating the tensor was fast. I cannot explain it...